# use try/except with psycopg2 or "with closing"?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using Psycopg2 in Python to access a PostgreSQL database. I'm curious if it's safe to use the `with closing()` pattern to create and use a cursor, or if I should use an explicit `try/except` wrapped around the query. My question is concerning inserting or updating, and transactions.

As I understand it, all Psycopg2 queries occur within a transaction, and it's up to calling code to commit or rollback the transaction. If within a `with closing(...` block an error occurs, is a rollback issued? In older versions of Psycopg2, a rollback was explicitly issued on `close()` but this is not the case anymore (see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.close).

My question might make more sense with an example. Here's an example using `with closing(...`

```
with closing(db.cursor()) as cursor:
     cursor.execute("""UPDATE users                    
             SET password = %s, salt = %s
             WHERE user_id = %s""",
             (pw_tuple[0], pw_tuple[1], user_id))
     module.rase_unexpected_error()
     cursor.commit()
```

What happens when module.raise_unexpected_error() raises its error? Is the transaction rolled back? As I understand transactions, I either need to commit them or roll them back. So in this case, what happens?

Alternately I could write my query like this:

```
cursor = None
try:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE users                    
            SET password = %s, salt = %s
            WHERE user_id = %s""",
            (pw_tuple[0], pw_tuple[1], user_id))
    module.rase_unexpected_error()
    cursor.commit()
except BaseException:
    if cursor is not None:
        cursor.rollback()
finally:
    if cursor is not None:
        cursor.close()
```

Also I should mention that I have no idea if Psycopg2's connection class `cursor()` method could raise an error or not (the documentation doesn't say) so better safe than sorry, no?

Which method of issuing a query and managing a transaction should I use?

Comment: I realize this is a super old question but I'd like to know where your opinion stands on this now. Also why not use a try/except block in the `with closing(...` ?
I'm asking because I'm encountering issues regarding some [changes to psycopg2 in version 2.5.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit)

It explicitly states that a commit should occur if no exception is raised using try/except statement if no exception is raised and rollback otherwise. However my experience proves otherwise and I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really say. My current job doesn't have me working with PostgreSQL which means I haven't used Psycopg2 in a while. I haven't thought about this in a while, and I don't remember in what direction I went before (and I no longer have access to that source code).

Comment: Not a problem, I expected so! Your question is just the only remotely related question I could find. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: (6 years later :) The docs also say for the `rollback()` method "if the connection is used in a with statement, the (rollback) method is automatically called if an exception is raised in the with block", so you should use a `with` context manager, and `try / except` inside that if you need to handle specific exceptions (probably not), and don't worry about explicitly calling `cursor.rollback()`. I also recommend setting conn.autocommit = True.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Your link to the Psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.close) kind of explains it itself, no?

> ... Note that closing a connection without committing the changes first will
>   **cause any pending change to be discarded as if a ROLLBACK was
>   performed** (unless a different isolation level has been selected: see
>   set_isolation_level()).
>
> Changed in version 2.2: previously an explicit ROLLBACK was issued by
>   Psycopg on close(). The command could have been sent to the backend at
>   an inappropriate time, so **Psycopg currently relies on the backend to
>   implicitly discard uncommitted changes**. Some middleware are known to
>   behave incorrectly though when the connection is closed during a
>   transaction (when status is STATUS_IN_TRANSACTION), e.g. PgBouncer
>   reports an unclean server and discards the connection. To avoid this
>   problem you can ensure to terminate the transaction with a
>   commit()/rollback() before closing.

So, unless you're using a different isolation level, or using PgBouncer, your first example should work fine. However, if you desire some finer-grained control over exactly what happens during a transaction, then the try/except method might be best, since it parallels the database transaction state itself.

Comment: It looks like, when using "with closing()" (psycopg2 2.4.5), if a SQL exception is raised, the transaction remains in progress. Attempting to do anything else on the database connection after that will cause an "InternalError: current transaction is aborted" error to be raised.

Comment: @skyler: So the transaction isn't rolled back, then? Does any subsequent connection to the database fail as well, or just the one that received the error?

Comment: no, it doesn't look like it's being rolled back. If I close the connection and ropen it, I can then issue new queries. I haven't tried opening another connection, separate from the errored one, and attempting a query on that.